# How to get first n objects by unique keys/values

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array with hundreds of objects which contain geolocation data like so:

```
var geoArray = [
  {
    name: "a",
    latitude: 34.0500,
    longitude: 118.2500
    ...
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    latitude: 40.7127,
    longitude: 74.0059,
    ...
  },
  ...
];
```

I want to grab the first 10 objects of each unique latitude/longitude pair and put these sets of objects into a new array. What would be an efficient way to accomplish this? I'm open to using lodash or underscore.

Using underscore's `uniq` I could do the following, but this only gets me the first object based on lat/lng rather than the first 10:

```
_.uniq(geoArray,function(element) { return element.latitude + "_" + element.longitude});
```

This is `_uniq`'s actual definition:

`_.uniq(array, [isSorted], [iteratee])`

My desired function would basically look like:
`_.uniq(array, [isSorted], [iteratee], [limit])` where `limit` is 1 by default, but I would like to enter 10. I know I could first grab the unique lat/lng pairs then find which objects have each of them and push them to an array at most 10 times, etc. But I was hoping there was a more efficient way.

Here is the exact code that works after applying the very helpful answer below:

```
function getUnique(arr, limit) {
  var indices = [];
  var out = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
     var location = arr[i].latitude + '_' + arr[i].longitude;
     if (indices.indexOf(location) === -1) {
       out.push(arr.filter(function (el) {
         return el.latitude + '_' + el.longitude === location
       }).slice(0, limit));
       indices.push(location);
     }
  }
  return out;
}
```

Comment: You should post the code you've attempted in the question. Please don't expect us to solve the problem for you without trying to solve it yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I think I understand what your question is about, [this is the most efficient method](http://jsperf.com/uniquerly/3) I could think of. It returns an array of groups of objects with the same id. You'll have to adapt it for your data*, but this is the gist.

```
function getUnique(arr, limit) {
    var indices = [];
    var out = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
       var id = arr[i].id;
       if (indices.indexOf(id) === -1) {
         out.push(arr.filter(function (el) {
             return el.id === id;
         }).slice(0, limit));
         indices.push(id);
       }
    }
    return out;
}

getUnique(arr, 3);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/efmeo80L/3/)

- I used a simple array because I didn't want to have to create lots of objects with lat/lon coords in this instance.

Comment: Reduce requires processing the entire sequence. Not a big deal for few hundred elements, but it cannot terminate early.

Comment: Thank you, but this gives me the first 10 unique objects based on lat/lng rather than the first 10 objects of each unique lat/lng. What I'm aiming for is basically underscore's `uniq` method, but with the first 10 occurrences returned rather than just the first 1.

Comment: @MattDionis, how about this?

Comment: I think this will do it! Thanks, and sorry for not providing more details in the original post. I've since added to it. Looking at underscore's source code is actually pretty interesting stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Use lodash group by:

```
var grouped = _.groupBy(geoArray, function(item){return item.lat + ',' + item.long; };
var valuesByLocation = _.values(grouped);
var valuesByLocation_First10 = _.map(valuesByLocation, function(value){ return _.take(value, 10); });
```

You could obviously combine all to a one liner using either _.partial or the chaining.